# JavaScript canplay event attached to window object?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have the following piece of code in `<head>`:

```
var canplay = false;
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
        canplay = true;
    }, true);
}
```

And later I have a `addEventListener` attached to video, but it's not firing because `canplay` is already being fired (and handled from the code above).

That's okay, but why we attach that event listener to `window` object and why it works?

Comment: Is all your code in `<head>` ? Can you show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And later I have a addEventListener attached to video, but it's not firing

`canplay` event does not fire continuously. It will only fire at the time, when the buffer is ready to be played. Since you say you **later** attach a listener to the video object; maybe you've missed the time when the event was fired. But you can check anytime via `video.readyState >= video.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA`

> why we attach that event listener to window object and why it works?

Spec allows it.

- [From W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/webappapis.html): the event handlers (and their corresponding event handler event types) that must be supported by all HTML elements, as both content attributes and IDL attributes, and on Document and Window objects...
- [From Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html): You can install event listeners on the media element or any of its parents, up to and including the document body...